# Add a disabled class to letter's filter button when no letter's class in content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page has albums. I add classes to each album according to first letter of an artist inside the album's div to filter content.

The purpose is to disable a letter's filter button if there is no artist begins with this specific letter.

I try to do something, but of course, it doesn't work, have you any idea?
The relevant code is in the third part of javascript. I have no problem with "Alphabetical filter" and "Scroll to top page".

```js
// Disabled button if no artist begin with specific letter in page
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".filter-button").ready(function(){
    var letterAcount = $(".letterA").length;
    var letterBcount = $(".letterB").length;
    var letterCcount = $(".letterC").length;
    var letterDcount = $(".letterD").length;
    var letterEcount = $(".letterE").length;
    var letterFcount = $(".letterF").length;
    var letterGcount = $(".letterG").length;
    var letterHcount = $(".letterH").length;
    var letterIcount = $(".letterI").length;
    var letterJcount = $(".letterJ").length;
    var letterKcount = $(".letterK").length;
    var letterLcount = $(".letterL").length;
    var letterMcount = $(".letterM").length;
    var letterNcount = $(".letterN").length;
    var letterOcount = $(".letterO").length;
    var letterPcount = $(".letterP").length;
    var letterQcount = $(".letterQ").length;
    var letterRcount = $(".letterR").length;
    var letterRcount = $(".letterS").length;
    var letterTcount = $(".letterT").length;
    var letterUcount = $(".letterU").length;
    var letterVcount = $(".letterV").length;
    var letterWcount = $(".letterW").length;
    var letterXcount = $(".letterX").length;
    var letterYcount = $(".letterY").length;
    var letterZcount = $(".letterZ").length;
  
    if($letterAcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterBcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterCcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterDcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterEcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterFcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterGcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterHcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterIcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterJcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterKcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterLcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterMcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterNcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterOcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterPcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
        if($letterQcount.length == 0)
   $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterRcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterScount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterTcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterUcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterVcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterWcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterXcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterYcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    if($letterZcount.length == 0)
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
  });
});
```

```css
   

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #cc6110;
  background-color: #e3e0ce; /* Nenesse 8/17/2017: New color */
  background-image: url(images/background-woodenfloor.jpg); /* Nenesse 8/16/2017: New background image */ 
}

.title {
  font-size : 24pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #cc6110; /* Nenesse 8/16/2017: New color */
}

a {
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #285e80; /* Nenesse 8/16/2017: New color instead of #FFFFFF */
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #cc6110; 
}

a:hover img#thumbimage {
  text-decoration: none;
} 
.artist { 
  /* Nenesse 8/16/2017: New class for different color */
  color: #285e80;
  font-size:12pt;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.album {     
  /* Nenesse 8/16/2017: new class for different color */
  color: #cc6110;
  font-size:10pt;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.card {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: inherit;
}

.filter-button {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #cc6110;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #cc6110;
}

.filter-button:hover {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #cc6110;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #285e80;
}

.btn.filter-button:after {
  background: #285e80;
}

.btn-default:active .filter-button:active {
  background: #285e80;
  color: white;
}

.btn{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.btn:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 100% 50% 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
}

.btn:hover:after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}

.row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right:0;
}

/* BackToTopPage button */
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  background: rgb(40, 94, 128);
  background: rgba(40, 94, 128, 0.8);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
  -moz-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.back-to-top i {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 16px;
  top: 13px;
  font-size: 19px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.back-to-top:hover {
  background: rgba(204,97,16, 0.9);
}

.back-to-top:hover i {
  color: #fff;
  top: 5px;
}

/* BackToTopPage tooltip */
.tooltip-inner {
  color:white;
  font-weight:400;
  background-color:rgba(40, 94, 128, 0.9);
}

.tooltip.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=right] .arrow::before, .tooltip.bs-tooltip-top .arrow::before { 
  border-top-color: rgba(40, 94, 128, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
  <title>Album List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>
  <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="enhanced exportindex_wood.css"></link>
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a id="back-to-top" href="#" class="back-to-top btn-custom" role="button" title="Go Top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
      <i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="color: #cc6110;" align="center">
        <h1 class="title">Album List</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterA">A</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterB">B</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterC">C</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterD">D</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterE">E</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterF">F</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterG">G</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterH">H</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterI">I</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterJ">J</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterK">K</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterL">L</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterM">M</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterN">N</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterO">O</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterP">P</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterQ">Q</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterR">R</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterS">S</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterT">T</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterU">U</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterV">V</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterW">W</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterX">X</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterY">Y</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="letterZ">Z</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="row">
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterB">
      <a href="details/8660.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/8660t.jpg" alt="Image Afrikan Basement - Unreleased Extended Versions - Disc 1"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Bolla</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">Afrikan Basement - Unreleased Extended Versions - Disc 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterB">
      <a href="details/8666.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/8666t.jpg" alt="Image Afrikan Basement - Unreleased Extended Versions - Disc 2"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Bolla</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">Afrikan Basement - Unreleased Extended Versions - Disc 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterJ letterD">
      <a href="details/8881.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/8881t.jpg" alt="Image A Journey To Rotterdam"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Jepht&#233; Guillaume | Diephuis</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">A Journey To Rotterdam</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterL">
      <a href="details/412.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/412t.jpg" alt="Image La Home Box - Disc 4"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Laurent Garnier</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">La Home Box - Disc 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterL letterT letterB">
      <a href="details/376.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/376t.jpg" alt="Image La Home Box - Disc 3"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Laurent Garnier | Traumer | Bambounou</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">La Home Box - Disc 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterL letterT letterH">
      <a href="details/447.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/447t.jpg" alt="Image La Home Box - Disc 5"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Laurent Garnier | Traumer | Husbands</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">La Home Box - Disc 5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterL letterU letterM">
      <a href="details/305.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/305t.jpg" alt="Image La Home Box - Disc 1"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Laurent Garnier | Uner | Marc Romboy</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">La Home Box - Disc 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterL letterV letterC">
      <a href="details/341.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/341t.jpg" alt="Image La Home Box - Disc 2"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Laurent Garnier | Voiski | Copy Paste Soul</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">La Home Box - Disc 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterM">
      <a href="details/10344.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/10344t.jpg" alt="Image Dj-Kicks - Disc 1"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Moodymann</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">Dj-Kicks - Disc 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterM">
      <a href="details/10307.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/10307t.jpg" alt="Image Dj-Kicks - Disc 2"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Moodymann</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">Dj-Kicks - Disc 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterM">
      <a href="details/10124.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/10124t.jpg" alt="Image Dj-Kicks - Disc 3"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Moodymann</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">Dj-Kicks - Disc 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterS letterL letterA letterR">
      <a href="details/8897.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/8897t.jpg" alt="Image Hagagatan Remixed"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Svreca | Lucy | Alexey Volkov | R&#248;dh&#229;d</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">Hagagatan Remixed</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterT">
      <a href="details/10673.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/10673t.jpg" alt="Image North Star / Silent Space"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">Tale Of Us</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">North Star / Silent Space</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterT">
      <a href="details/8820.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/8820t.jpg" alt="Image Goddess Of A New Dawn"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">The Bayara Citizens</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">Goddess Of A New Dawn</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterT">
      <a href="details/8719.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/8719t.jpg" alt="Image Mofo Congoietric"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">The Bayara Citizens</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">Mofo Congoietric</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterT">
      <a href="details/9074.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/9074t.jpg" alt="Image The Girl And The Chameleon - Disc 1"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">The Exaltics</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">The Girl And The Chameleon - Disc 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterT">
      <a href="details/9033.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/9033t.jpg" alt="Image The Girl And The Chameleon - Disc 2"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">The Exaltics</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">The Girl And The Chameleon - Disc 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="card bg-transparent col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filter letterT letterJ">
      <a href="details/8777.html">
        <img class="card-img-top rounded img-fluid" src="images/8777t.jpg" alt="Image Joaquin Joe Claussell Mixes"/>
      </a>
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center artist">The Lower East Side Pipes | Joe Claussell</h4>
        <p class="card-text text-center album">Joaquin Joe Claussell Mixes</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <br/>
    <div class="value col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" align="left">20/09/2017 01:14:33</div>
    <div class="value col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" align="Right">Powered by 
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.collectorz.com/music" title="Music Collector">Music Collector</a> &amp; JHR Enhanced Details template
    </div>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="indexfilter.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Correct your script error first.

Comment: also we only need to see the relevant parts of your code. when you add code to the question it should be the minimal amount of code to understand what's going on. so we only need one html button, and basically only the function you want us to look at.

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in your code: correct it first and verify that your code snippet is working. p/s: It should be `length` not `lenght`.

Comment: That's not the only issue: incorrectly wrapped function calls, incorrect event binding... among many others. It is unclear what you're trying to do with your code.

Comment: I know I'm a noob, sorry about that, just want to add disabled class to button element when there is no element to filter in albums list (no artist begin with whatever letter).

Comment: no worries, it clearly happens to the best of us ;-). just... before you post a question on here, you need to try as many things as possible. bang your head on the problem before you ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way of doing this that would remove your duplication and do what you want it to do would be to do something like:

```
$(".filter-button").each(function(idx, item){
  let txt = $(item).text();
  let className = '.letter' + txt;
  if($(className).length === 0){
    $(item).addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

or

```
$(".filter-button").each(function(idx, item){
  let className = $(item).data('filter');
  if($(className).length === 0){
    $(item).addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

---

## Protip:

in general, anytime you find yourself copy pasting something or writing the same thing only slightly differently for example

```
var letterZcount = $(".letter{blah}").length;

if($letter{blah}count.length < 3)
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
```

You either need to extract something into a reusable function or you need to rethink the way you're addressing it. This is what loops are for.

Answer (score 0):

Another tip: You could make your `letterXcount` declarations much shorter by doing something like:

```

```
let start = 65, 
    end = 91, 
    letters = [],
    holder = {};

// Get every letter of the alphabet
for(var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    letters.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
}

// Bind them to a property on an object.
// You could also use the `window` object to do the same thing.
letters.forEach(val => {
    let localLabel = `letter${val}count`;
    let localVal = $(`.letter${val}`).length;

    holder[localLabel] = localVal; 
});
```

```